# removing quotes from array value

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array value

```
0 => "2"
```

Now since im using an API it is very important that there are no qoutes (as the call will mis interperate it)

so i tried the following:

```
stripslashes($string);
```

However this did not help any ideas?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. Do you mean you want the array to be integers?

Comment: Yeah i basicly want to convert the string to an integer

Comment: If you got that from a `var_dump()` or `print_r()`, the value is a string but is not actually quoted. It is only displayed that way.

Comment: So you have an array like `array(0 => "2")`, or `array('0 => "2"')`? It's always helpful to include actual executable code, not vague code fragments without enough context.

Comment: What makes you think that `stripslashes` will do _any_ good? Look at the signature: `string stripslashes ( string $str )`, It clearly returns a string, not an int! so it has _nothing_ to do with the type, nor does it have anything to do with quotes (slash => /, quote: ") [RTFM](http://www.php.net/stripslashes)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$yourArray = array_map('intval', $yourArray);
```

if you want to convert all values 
or 
`intval($string)` on a string

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over the array and convert them to integer

```
$count = count($arr);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) {
   $arr[$i] = (int)$arr[$i];
}
```